# Adding an object to a multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, multidimensional-array, html5-canvas

I have a tile object declared as follows:

```
var tile = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: canvas.width / numoftiles,
    h: canvas.width / numoftiles,
    color: "#FFFFFF"
};
```

I have a multidimensional array to store a number of these tile objects, which I declare like so:

```
var tiles = [[]];
```

I loop through the length of my canvas adding these tiles to fill the screen like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < (canvas.height / numoftiles); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < (canvas.width / numoftiles); j++) {
        tiles[i][j] = new tile();
    }
}
```

My error occurs on the line:

```
tiles[i][j] = new tile();
```

The JavaScript console returns "Uncaught TypeError: tile is not a constructor"

How can I insert tile objects to a specific location in my multidimensional array?

Comment: `tiles[i][j] = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an object constructor, and then create objects of the constructed type:

```
function Tile() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.w = canvas.width / numoftiles;
  this.h = canvas.width / numoftiles;
  this.color = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Now you can use:

```
var tile = new Tile();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
var tiles = [[]];
```

you've only created `tiles[0]`. In order to assign to `tiles[i][j]`, `tiles[i]` has to be an array, but it doesn't exist for any `i` other than `0`. You need to create the sub-arrays in your loop.

As for the error you're getting, that's because `tile` is just an object, not a constructor function. If you haven't defined a constructor, just assign the object literal in the loop.

```
var tiles = [];
for (i = 0; i < (canvas.height / numoftiles); i++) {
    tiles[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < (canvas.width / numoftiles); j++) {
        tiles[i][j] = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: canvas.width / numoftiles,
            h: canvas.width / numoftiles,
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: My error still persists using this solution. The JavaScript console still returns that tile is not a constructor.

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tile` is an object literal, you can not use the operator `new` on it.

`new` operator can only be used if you have a constructor function.

[This SO has good explanation about how to clone objects:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)